# How do I get four fields as a row in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, row

How do I get four fields as a row in a MySQL table?

Table structure:

```
id     name
------------
1     John
2     Doe
3     M
4     King
5     Mark
6     Someone
7     Thing
8     Super
```

The html output should be:

```
John - Doe - M - King
Mark - Someone - Thing - Super
```

etc..

I have no code samples as I have no clue where to begin.  I have over 300,000 rows.

Comment: You just put the fields that you need in your query. `SELECT name, lastname, initial, otherfield, anotherone, one_more FROM yourtable` and use PHP to format it how you want.

Comment: Is the data really scattered across 4 rows consistently like that? If it is 4 fields you can use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat.

Comment: Mike, i only have one field as u can see from the table structure.

Chris85, yes its consistant, after every 4 rows new cycle starts.

Comment: @Gunarves I didn't notice how your data was structured. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Also, I would strongly consider restructuring it to something more logical. How you have it is crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
$mysqli = database::connect(); // Get a connection
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM tablename ORDER BY id ASC")) {
    $i = 0;
    $data = "";
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $data .= $row['name'];
        $i++;
        if ($i < 4) {
            $data .= " - ";
         } else {
            $data .= "<br />";
            $i = 0;
         }
    }
    $result->close();
}
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach to achieve what you want would be to consider each group of 4 consecutive `id` values as a group, and then do a group concatenation over each set of records:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`name` SEPARATOR ' - ')
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY (id - 1) DIV 4
```

Comment: I suspect that this is too literal an interpretation of the requirement.

Comment: Nobody's ever loved me that way before. I'm lost for words. :-)

Comment: @Strawberry You talking to yourself there?

Comment: @Mike I had added a comment where I said that I love eating Strawberries but I don't like them when they leave bad comments.  I deleted it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Haha. I thought it was something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

you can try use remainder of the division `%` for get remainder number 4. for example

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++) {
      echo $row['name'] ;
      if($i%4==0) {
         echo '<br/>';
      } else {
         echo ' - ';
      }
   }
```